# How specific is RAM to a CPU?

Tags: memory, cpu

I am fully aware that you need to get RAM with a supported speed (1333mhz or 1600mhz in my case). However, must a CPU also support the RAM in someway I am unaware of. I ask because my RAM just produced over 60000 errors on memtest, regardless of which motherboard slot I was in.

I have had blue screens from the start really but since it was my first PC build I guess I was in denial thinking that nothing would go wrong so I only tested it now. The memory I have can be found [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Patriot-PSD38G13332-Signature-1333MHZ-Memory/dp/B0075U12H8) while the CPU can be found [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00EF1G98W/?tag=pcp0f-21). If you scroll down the RAM's page it says

> Compatible with Intel® 2nd Gen CPUs

which obviously - mine is not.

So my main question is - do CPU's only support limited selections of RAM and, if so, would I be better getting something like [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Crucial-Ballistix-BLS8G3D169DS3CEU-PC3-12800-Memory/dp/B00DHCO77U/ref=cm_cr_pr_sims_t) which was made in 2013 as opposed to 2012. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the CPU now has a built in controller and talks to the memory more directally than it did before, which becomes a bit more important/critical that the tiny wires in the cpu socket are all connecting proper (one build concideration).  I just mention that because rarely a really bad ram problem was a CPU connecting to the socket problem, something that was way more rare back in 775 sockets.

&

No, if the memory is right for the motherboard used, it connects correctally it is the correct type and all (ddr1,2,3) or whatever label they are using this week. the Correct voltage, Then if the timings are right for the speed it is operated at , then it should still work.

You bought patriot memory (no comment) from the bargain basement , that could be the only problem you have :-)

It is best to look in your motherboard manuel or online for the "memory/ram compatability list" that the makers of the motherboard provide, for your specific motherboard.  The list includes memories that the manufactures have tested with the board.
It is not always possible to get these Rams that are on the list, but the list can still be a very good start for seeing what was tested, and what works.

It is possible that a person could re-time the memory (in the bios) you have and get it to work error free, doing that isn't fun or really long term (lose the settings and your back in fail land)  It is possible that the memory would work at a lower setting. Adjusting a lot of stuff to get it to work is possible.  I have achieved completly error free operation out of rams people would swear would never work with a specific board, but getting the correct ram for the board was a WAY better idea.
It is possible ,  people have messed up those tiny connections in the cpu socket, and get really bad ram erroring going.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And yesm I was going to get some sweet RAM but for some reason amazon displayed the price incorrectly and it was put in my basket for £50 more than advertised so I just chucked the first one I saw in.

Answer (score 1):

It's **not the CPU (at-least not for older PCs)** that influences the selection of RAM on a machine, it's more related to what **Motherboard** you have.

For example Consider, two CPUs

[Intel® Pentium® 4 Processor 519K](http://ark.intel.com/products/27458/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-519K-1M-Cache-3_06-GHz-533-MHz-FSB)

[Intel® Core™ i7-4790K Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/80807/Intel-Core-i7-4790K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_40-GHz)

If you go through the specifications you will find that the **older CPU has no Memory Specifications** while **the newer one has some Memory Specifications**.
So in the second case that factors in along with what motherboard you have. So always

**First see what Motherboard and CPU you have then you go for RAM**

and not the other way round.
Some other general tips:

1. **you absolutely can't mix**, it's DDR with DDR2, or DDR2 with DDR3, and
   so on (they won't even fit in the same slots).
2. You want to make sure each stick has the **same CAS latency, timings, and voltage.**
3. **Mixing RAM speed, however, is a slightly different matter**. In theory, if you had to, you could mix, say, this Patriot model (DDR3 1333) with this Corsair model (DDR3 1600), since they have the same CAS latency, timings, and recommended voltage. Your motherboard would probably just automatically underclock the faster one, and you wouldn't run into any problems. Thus, it's possible, but note that when you start mixing speeds, a chain is only as strong as its weakest link, so to speak. Your RAM will only run at the speed of the slowest DIMM, unless you wanted to overclock the others.
4. If buying 2 or more modules of RAM, **ALWAYS GO FOR THE SAME COMPANY, BRAND, MODEL NO.**

***None of this necessarily guarantees functioning RAM, of course—you may be greeted with the Blue Screen of Death if your DIMMs just don't like each other (or your motherboard doesn't like one of the DIMMs).***

Source: Experience , [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5598716/what-are-the-rules-on-mixing-two-different-types-of-ram)